# SQl : How to add new column by joining two same tables with aggregate values?

Tags: mysql, sql

The parent table has four variables ( ID, Type, Persons). Below output has been generated using distinct combination of 'ID' and 'Type' and aggregate as "counts' with no filters. I want to add another column next to it as 'missing_counts' based on filter, if 'Persons' value is Null in the same Table.

```
Id       Type            Counts
EUR      Accounts        3600
GBP      Accounts        3673
EUR     Science          1724
CNY     Physics         1608
GBP     Physics         4437
CNY     Chemistry       5070
EUR     Chemistry       1499
GBP     Chemistry       33752
EUR     Math            5155
```

The expected output

```
Id       Type            Counts  Missing_Counts
EUR      Accounts        3600     200
GBP      Accounts        3673
EUR     Science          1724      400
CNY     Physics         1608
GBP     Physics         4437
CNY     Chemistry       5070
EUR     Chemistry       1499      600
GBP     Chemistry       33752
EUR     Math            5155      800
```

My work so far:

```
SELECT distinct p.Id, p.Type, count (*) as Counts
  FROM Table1 as p
  group by p.Id, p.Type

  left join (SELECT distinct q.Id, q.Type, count (*) as missing_count
             FROM Table1 as q
             where Persons is Null
             group by q.Id, q.Type)
  ON p.Id = q.Id and p.Type = q.Type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join subqueries

```
SELECT 
    p.Id, p.Type, p.counts, q.missing_count
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        p.Id, p.Type, COUNT(*) AS Counts
    FROM
        Table1 AS p
    GROUP BY p.Id , p.Type) p
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        q.Id, q.Type, COUNT(*) AS missing_count
    FROM
        Table1 AS q
    WHERE
        Persons IS NULL
    GROUP BY q.Id , q.Type) q ON p.Id = q.Id AND p.Type = q.Type
```

Comment: the fist select statement of your answer showing error it seems and also the placement of table alias q. Please check again

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.
Incorrect syntax near 'q'.

Comment: No it doesn't see https://dbfiddle.uk/nhAW8-CC

Comment: Yes. I got it. I missed out the closing brackets of alias p. Thank you again !